# Unable to install a NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, typescript, karma-runner

I'm trying to install a NodeJS module called "karma-typescript-preprocessor" (See: https://npmjs.org/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor), but I'm getting an error when trying to install it. It is used by Karma to compile typescript files before testing. Here's the error I get. How do I fix this?

```
C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core>npm install karma-typescript-preprocessor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-typescript-preprocessor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-typescript-preprocessor
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: karma-typescript-preprocessor@'>=0.1.0-0 <0.2.0-0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.2","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:698:17)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "instal
l" "karma-typescript-preprocessor"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core>
```

I have added the dependency to package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "express": "3.4.7",
        "ejs": "*",
        "less-middleware": "*",
        "formidable": "1.0.x",
        "socket.io": "0.9.x",
        "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "~0.1"
    }
```

I am trying to install the module in my project directory. If I try to install outside the Project directory, the module gets installed, but karma does not see it. Here's the error it throws:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "typescript", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket tyVcKoZygd-TRPnrm_WW
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket o5hgQaj7f4B8-Ovfm_WX
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket fvjPXprGmKQxWHROm_WY
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) ERROR
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
        at C:/Users/Anjan/WebstormProjects/Core/TsUnit/StartTest.ts:8
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) ERROR
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
        at C:/Users/Anjan/WebstormProjects/Core/TsUnit/StartTest.ts:8
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) ERROR
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
        at C:/Users/Anjan/WebstormProjects/Core/TsUnit/StartTest.ts:8
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) ERROR
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.363 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (1.162 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.643 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: Thanks "log", you are right! Version 0.0.1 has been remove from npm repository :), we should choose another version, I prefer latest version or best matched version `"karma-typescript-preprocessor": "*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"karma-typescript-preprocessor": "~0.1"` is invalid. Try `"karma-typescript-preprocessor": "0.0.6"`

run `npm info karma-typescript-preprocessor` to find which versions are available.

Comment: Thanks. Can you take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932617/karma-error-in-typescript